# Vue-CLI 3: How to include LESS files from outside of /src directory in webpack bundle?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, less, vue-cli-3

I'm looking for a way to include .less files that live outside of the /src directory of my Vue-Cli project into my webpack bundle. Need these .less files to **only be included in 'development' mode**.

When built in a Production environment, we'll need to link to external folder for styles which looks like: **/assets/styles/main.css**

**Directory Structure:**

```
Vue-Project
|-- /Styles
|   `-- app
|       `-- styles
|           |-- main.less
|           `-- atoms/modules/etc
|               `-- *.less
|-- /src
`-- vue.config.js
```

Should I be [Chaining WebPack](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-loader) or [Updating Loader Options](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders)?

**vue.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,

  configureWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      // mutate config for production...
    } else {
      // mutate for development...

      // CONFIG LESS FILES HERE?

    }
  }
};
```

Tried the following, but didn't work:

```
css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      less: {
        data: `@import "@/styles/main.less";`
        // @imported .less files from Styles/app/styles/main.less etc into src/styles/main.less
      }
    }
  }
```

Any guidance on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Turns out the "data" option only works for sass, not less loader.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to install these packages, less-loader will be required to convert the **.less** files into **.css** files.

```
npm install concurrently less less-loader less-watch-compiler --save-dev
```

Secondly, add `less-watcher.config.json` file in your root folder and place the following code in it.

```
{
    "watchFolder": "Styles/",
    "outputFolder": "Styles/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "runOnce": false,
    "enableJs": true
  }
```

Note that `watchFolder` should be the folder where all your **.less** files are loacated, and `outputFolder`is the folder where generated **.css** files will be placed.

Now in your `packages.json` file add this code inside **scripts** object

```
"start": "concurrently --kill-others \"less-watch-compiler --config less-watcher.config.json\" \"webpack-dev-server --open --mode development\""
```

This will ensure that whenever your run npm start it will regenerate the **.css** files before running the project.

Finally in your `index.js` file import the **.css** file

```
import "../Styles/app/main.css";
```

[Your folder/files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxIsL.png)